Multiple Public Function inside a single Public Function?
Each step gathers data from user input. This is public function from step1. Im trying to insert the data to the database but im getting mostly clientID error.
public function submitApplication($clientID, $managingHead, $managingHeadMobNum, $managingHeadTelNum, $natureBusiness, $psicNum, $psicDesc, $dateEstablishment, $numEmployees, $pcoName, $pcoMobNum, $pcoTelNum, $pcoEmail, $pcoAccredNo, $pcoAccredDate, $region, $province, $city, $barangay, $zipCode, $latitude, $longitude){
    global $conn;

    $query = "INSERT INTO application(clientID, appRegistration, appManager, appManagerContactNumber, appManagerTelephoneNumber, 
                                    appNatureBusiness, appPSICNum, appPSICDesc, appDateClient, appNumEmployees,
                                    appPCOName, appPCOMobileNumber, appPCOTelephoneNumber, appPCOEmail, appPCOAccredNo, 
                                    appPCODateAccred, appFaciRegion, appFaciProvince, appFaciCity, appFaciBarangay, 
                                    appFaciZip, appGeoLatitude, appGeoLongitude, appStatus)
            VALUES (?, CURDATE(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PROCESSING')";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssss', $clientID, $managingHead, $managingHeadMobNum, $managingHeadTelNum, 
                    $natureBusiness, $psicNum, $psicDesc, $dateEstablishment, $numEmployees, $pcoName, $pcoMobNum, 
                    $pcoTelNum, $pcoEmail, $pcoAccredNo, $pcoAccredDate, $region, $province, $city, $barangay, 
                    $zipCode, $latitude, $longitude);

    if ($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

Is there a way to insert submitapplication2 in the same public function?
public function submitApplication2($ecpID, $clientID, $permitType, $permitNumber, $dateIssued, $expiryDate, $placeIssuance, $permitFile) {
    global $conn;

    $query = "INSERT INTO ecp(ecpID, clientID, ecpPermitType, ecpPermitNo, ecpPermitDateIssued, ecpPermitExpiry, ecpPlaceInsurance, ecpPermitFIle)
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $ecpID, $clientID, $permitType, $permitNumber, $dateIssued, $expiryDate, $placeIssuance, $permitFile);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
}


Unrelated to your question, but $stmt->close(); is unreachable in both cases because both branches of your if return.

To your question, you should be able to either just call the other function, or move that code into the same function. Have you tried anything?

What do you mean by "getting mostly clientID error"? What is the exact error message?

hello, its saying it cannot read clientID error on step 2.

Please copy and paste the literal error message you are getting

Error: ClientID does not exist in the database.

Does the method submitApplication2 work at all, and you are just trying to optimize things? Or is it a broken method? Please show how you are getting the error message, too. The error message "ClientID does not exist in the database" sounds more like an application-level error, however maybe something is referencing a table called ClientID somewhere?

submitApplication2 is not working. im just looking for a way to merge them both.
